# Probabilities and random variable problem

Tags: probability, random-variables

Suppose we have a random variable X, and we are given the numerical values of its expectation as well as its s.d. (standard deviation). How can I go about finding the maximum value the probability of P(X=a) for some a integer? Thank you.

What I've done so far is trying to use the Chebyshev's inequality to bound the $P(x=a)$ by adding $P(x =< a)$ and $P(x >= a)$ side by side. I'm not sure whether that's a right approach though, or whether it'll give me the sharpests inequality/maximum value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach from scratch without using any probabilistic tools. Surely better bounds are available. Denote your variable by $X$ and let it take values $x_i$ with probabilities $p_i$. Assume the variance $V(X)$ of $X$ is positive and finite, otherwise the question is trivial. Now define $$Z=X-E(X),$$
so that $E(Z)=0$ and $V(Z)=V(X)$. Call $z_i=x_i-E(X)$.

But $V(Z)=E(Z^2)-(E(Z))^2=E(Z^2)=\sum z_i^2p_i$. Because all the summands are nonnegative, it holds for every $i$ that $z_i^2p_i\leq V(X)$ or equivalently that $p_i\leq V(X)/(x_i-E(X))^2$, assuming $x_i\neq E(X)$.

If $x_i=E(X)$, I can not offer a better upper bound than 1 in general for $p_i$, since you can (in general) always put very little probability mass symmetrically sufficiently far away from both sides of $E(X)$ so that you get the desired variance.
For example, let $X$ be such that $E(X)=0$, $V(X)=1$, with distribution defined by $P(X=0)=\alpha$, $P(X=y)=P(X=-y)=(1-\alpha)/2$, then $V(X)=2y^2(1-\alpha)/2$ so that by choosing $y$ sufficiently big, you may choose $\alpha$ as close to one as you like.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are asking the max value of $Pr(X=a)$, I assume $X$ is a discrete random variable. If I can assume to know the set of the values the discrete random variable take, then let  the alphabet of the discrete random variable be ${\cal A} = \left\{a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_N\right\}$. Now, we would like to find the PDF $p(X)$ such that $p(a_1)$ (w.l.o.g) is maximum subject to the constraint that $\sum_i a_i p(a_i) = \mu N$ and $\sum_i a_i^2 p(a_i) = \sigma^2 N$, where $\mu$ and $\sigma$ are the mean and standard deviation respectively. This I believe is a convex optimization problem (rather linear program):

$\max {\bf e}_1^T {\bf p}$

subject to ${\bf a}^T {\bf p} = \mu N$ and ${\bf b}^T{\bf p} = \sigma^2 N$,

where ${\bf e}_1 = \left(\begin{array}{c}1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0 \end{array}\right)$, ${\bf p} = \left(\begin{array}{c}p(a_1) \\ p(a_2) \\ p(a_3) \\ \vdots \\ p(a_N) \end{array}\right)$, ${\bf a} = \left(\begin{array}{c}a_1 \\ a_2 \\ a_3 \\ \vdots \\ a_N \end{array}\right)$ and ${\bf b} = \left(\begin{array}{c}a_1^2 \\ a_2^2 \\ a_3^2 \\ \vdots \\ a_N^2 \end{array}\right)$.

However, I have no clue on how to solve if you don't have the knowledge of the alphabet ${\bf A}$.